# Deleting from a mutableStateListOf using an index reference is deleting the last item in the list and not the item with the corresponding index

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So I'm looking to add a list of TextField insets to a screen. The list is dynamic, so with the click of a button underneath, the user can add a new TextField to the screen. When clicked the info from these TextFields will be looped through an added to the DB. Thats fine, i've got that working. However the user is also provided with a Delete icon to delete that TextField from the screen if needed.

So the inset would be something like:

```
data class ContactModel(
    val index : Int = 0,
    val info : ContactInsetModel
)
```

with info being a further sub data class with

```
data class ContactInsetModel(
    val index : Int,
    val deleteEntry : (Int) -> Unit,
    val nameEntered : (String) -> Unit,
    val telNoEntered : (String) -> Unit,
)
```

so when the delete icon in the inset is clicked, it will pass the index back to the screen to perform the delete. How it is handled in the screen is where the problem lies.

```
@Composable
fun DisplayAddContacts() {

    /** Holds list to be looped and added to DB **/
    val contactEntryList = remember { mutableStateListOf<ContactsEntity>() }

    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var number by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var uniqueRef by remember {mutableStateOf(0)}

    /** Holds list to be displayed on screen **/
    var insetModelList = remember {
        mutableStateListOf<ContactInsetModel>(
            ContactInsetModel(
                index = uniqueRef,
                deleteEntry = {},
                nameEntered = { name = it },
                telNoEntered = { number = it }
            )
        )
    }

    /** New list in an attempt to map an index to the inset **/
    val listOfEntries =
        insetModelList.mapIndexed { index, info ->
            ContactModel(
                index = index,
                info = info
            )
        }.toMutableList()

                for (i in listOfEntries) {
                    ContactInset().Create(contactModel = i)
                    updateContactsList(i.index, name, number, contactEntryList)
                }

                if (insetModelList.size < 6) {
                        Button(
                            text = "Add another",
                            callback = {
                                ++uniqueRef
                                insetModelList.add(
                                    ContactInsetModel(
                                        index = uniqueRef,
                                        deleteEntry = {

                                        /** THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUES LIE **/

                                        }
                                        nameEntered = { name = it },
                                        telNoEntered = { number = it }
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        ))
            },
            primaryButton = ButtonModel(
                text = "Save & Continue",
                fillMaxWidth = true,
                callback = {
                    contactEntryList.asReversed().forEach {
                        runBlocking {
                            viewModel.insertContact(
                                ContactsModel(
                                    it
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            ),
        )
}
```

So its the deleteEntry callback is where the issue lies. I have tried things like

```
deleteEntry = { index ->
     insetModelList.removeAll{
           it.index == index
     }
}
```

and

```
deleteEntry = { index ->
     insetModelList.removeAt(index)
}
```

I've tried filtering it to a new list

```
insetModelList = insetModelList.filter { it.index != index }.toMutableStateList()
```

The result is always the same - the last entry on the screen is the one that is deleted, not the one selected. Fairly stumped at this point

**EDIT : So it was suggested I make my example code a bit more minimal, so I have tried to do this below - as well as provide some visual representation of what I am talking about. So updated code sample below**

@Composable
private fun DisplayTextFieldList() {

```
var count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val name = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

val textFieldList = remember { mutableStateListOf<InputFieldModel>() }

/** ADDING FIRST TEXT FIELD TO THE SCREEN **/
if (count.value < 1) {
    textFieldList.add(
        InputFieldModel(
            deleteTextField = {
                textFieldList.removeAt(it)
            },
            name = {
                name.value = it
            }
        )
    )
}

count.value++

/** ADDING INDEX TO DELETE CORRECT ENTRY FROM LIST**/
val listForDisplay = textFieldList.mapIndexed { index, info ->
    InputFieldModelIndexed(
        index = index,
        info = info
    )
}

/** DISPLAYING LIST OF TEXTFIELDS TO SCREEN **/
listForDisplay.forEach {
      BasicTextFieldInset().Create(model = it)
 }
 Button(onClick = {
      /** ADD TEXTFIELD MODEL TO LIST AND SUBSEQUENTLY THE SCREEN**/
      textFieldList.add(
          InputFieldModel(
               deleteTextField = {
               /**  ATTEMPT TO REMOVE TEXTFIELD FROM THE LIST ACCORDING TO ITS INDEX **/
                    textFieldList.removeAt(it)
                },
                 name = {name.value = it}
             )
         )
     }
  ){Text("Add another")},
Button(onClick = {}){Text("Continue")}
```

}

So I end up with something like this after I click the 'Add another' button a few times

[image]

But if I were to click the de;ete icon at 'TextField 3', I would expect to see test3 disappear. instead, test3 remains and it is test5 which is removed from the list. I cannot see why this is happening

Comment: You should reduce the problem to a [mre]. Chances are you'll find the problem yourself while doing that.

Comment: Your problem looks like as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/76246080/5457853. Setting `key(some unique id) {}`inside mapIndexed or foreach might solve the issue